# Why isn't this.super() possible in java?

Tags: java, constructor, this, super

In the following example if I make a constructor of a class called example like so:

```
public class Example{

    public Example(){
        this.super();
    }

}
```

The above will not work because `javac Example.java` informs about following compilation error:

```
Example.java:3: error: illegal qualifier; Object is not an inner class
        this.super();
            ^
1 error
```

But shouldn't it work as instead of implicitly stating `this` by using `super()`, we are explicitly stating it by using `this`?

Comment: what is example?  If it's a constructor, it needs parentheses.

Comment: `super` is a keyword.

Comment: `super` is a special java keyword pointing to the parent class and not a field, method or constructor of your object

Comment: For starters, the semantics of `this.super()` would be fully equivalent to `super()`. There is no reason why adding `this.` would help you. You don't need 2 ways to do the same thing.

Comment: @Michael While true, it doesn't answer the question, and doesn't explain why you can use either `this.someInstanceMethod()` and `someInstanceMethod()`, so it's also not a reason.

Comment: @DaveNewton It answers the question perfectly well. You don't need 2 ways to do the same thing. The fact that there are other parts of the language that allow you to do the same thing in 2 ways is irrelevant. Why isn't there an alias for `this` called `flibble`? Because it's not useful.

Comment: @Michael "Not needing two ways to do the same thing" isn't a *reason*, it's a *decision*. That aside: there's an *actual* reason why `this.super()` isn't valid, and that technical reason is at odds with "because you don't need two ways to do the same thing", because of the semantics of `this.super()` means it's *not* the same thing.

Comment: @DaveNewton No. "Will this make the language better or easier to use? Do we want to spend time and effort to support it?" are the questions, "No" is the decision, and what I have outlined is the reason. There is no technical reason why it is not possible. There are no semantics of `this.super()` since it is not part of the language.

Comment: @Michael The JLS disagrees, but ok. There are (at least) two *actual* reasons why `this.super()` is invalid. What you've outlined is *true*, but not the actual reason.

Comment: @Michael You've already commented on the answer with the citation? In any case, I will agree to disagree; to me what you're saying is not the actual reason.

Comment: @DaveNewton I dislike that answer since it refers to qualified superclass constructor invocations which this is not. It's *qualified* in the sense that `this` has been added as a qualifier but that's not the same thing. The best I can find in the JLS is "Unqualified superclass constructor invocations begin with the keyword super (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments)." That is a statement. A definition of the behaviour. And that's just the thing: the JLS pretty much universally does not justify its design decisions. It's simply a specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although invoking a superclass constructor by calling `super(args)` looks like it’s a regular method call, that syntax is actually different from a typical method call and isn’t subject to the same rules. For example:

1. You can only use `super(args)` in a constructor.
2. You can only use `super(args)` as the first line of a constructor.

In that sense, it probably helps to think of this not as a method call, but simply as a way of telling Java what you want to do to initialize the superclass.

Because this isn’t a typical method call, the rules for regular method calls don’t apply to it. As a result, you can’t prefix it with `this.` to make the receiver object explicit. There’s no fundamental reason why the Java language designers couldn’t have made this syntax legal; they just chose not to do so.

Answer (score 3):

The [JLS, Section 8.8.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1), controls the specifications for explicit constructor invocations.  It is possible in the grammar to specify `this.super()`.

> *Primary* . *[TypeArguments]* `super` ( *[ArgumentList]* ) ;

And a ["Primary" expression can be `this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-Primary).  Therefore, `this.super()` is a legal expression according to the *grammar* of the Java language, but that's not enough.  It's not legal according to the semantics of such an expression.

> *Qualified superclass constructor invocations* begin with a *Primary* expression or an *ExpressionName*. They allow a subclass constructor to explicitly specify the newly created object's immediately enclosing instance with respect to the direct superclass (§8.1.3). This may be necessary when the superclass is an inner class.

The semantics indicate that here, `this` is attempting to indicate an enclosing instance, not the current object instance.  The compiler error you get isn't the clearest, but here, `this` is attempting to reference the enclosing class of the superclass, but `Object` does not have an enclosing class.

```
public class J {
    public J() {
        this.super();
    }
}

J.java:17: error: illegal qualifier; Object is not an inner class
        this.super();
            ^
1 error
```

Let's attempt to use `this` as an enclosing instance.  Class `J` has an inner class `K`, and `Foo` attempts to subclass `J.K`.

```
class J {
    public J() { }
    public class K {}
}
class Foo extends J.K {
    public Foo() {
        this.super();
    }
}
```

The error now is:

```
J.java:21: error: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
            this.super();
            ^
1 error
```

I can only get it to work with a primary expression other than `this`.

```
class Foo extends J.K {
    public Foo() {
        new J().super();
    }
}
```

A semantics error, not a grammar error, prevents you from using `this.super()`.

Comment: Wouldn't `public Foo(J instance) { instance.this.super() }` also work? Intuitively, it seems like it ought to, at least from a syntactic perspective. It does seem deeply weird though.

Comment: @DanielPryden Compiler error message: `error: not an enclosing class: J`.  It needs an instance of `J`, not the `J` class itself.

Comment: @DanielPryden '*Intuitively*', are you sure about that? Why should `instance.this` be legal? What would it return...? The instance itself? Seems completely unintuitive.

Comment: One way to have (partially) `this.super();` at start of constructor could be using fact that we can use `Outer.this` from Inner classes to explicitly point Outer instance in which that Inner class is declared. Demo:: https://ideone.com/aQGZc3 where we can see `Outer.this.super();`.

Comment: @Michael: OK, "intuitively" is a stretch. I was thinking of "qualified this" syntax, where something like `J.this.someMethod()` *is* legal syntax. Similarly, instance-level `new` for inner classes: `instance.new Foo()` is legal syntax too. It's not absurd to extend that to `this` somehow, although now that I think about it, the *combination* of `this` and `super` pretty much is nonsensical.

Comment: Yes, @Pshemo, that was what I was thinking of, but I confused the syntax. I'm glad to see it works after all!

Answer (score 0):

In Java classes are initialized top down. So if you make a class that extends object, it calls object's constructor then it calls your class's.

This is also the reason you can't initialize any fields before calling super, your class hasn't been created yet. `this` doesn't refer to anything as the template of the object hasn't been constructed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

More information